# How to update data on firebase realtime database?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

In my project i need to update data in firebase. Firstly i write and made the first data:

```
set(ref(db, 'users/' + res.data.localId), {          
            name: name,
            surname: surname,
            email: email,
            countTrains: 0
          }).then(() => {
             console.log('Made new account');    
        })  
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            });
```

Then i need to update the feeld **countTrains**:

```
 update(ref(db, 'users/' + user.localId), {          
      countTrains: countTrain,
    }).then(() => {
      alert('data updated!');    
  })  
      .catch((error) => {
          alert(error);
      });
```

But it doesn't work and takes an exception like: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded, js engine: hermes.
Please, help

UPDATE:
I take the param of count from another Stack Screen by

```
 const countTrain = route.params.count
```

The source look like:

```
  const [count, setCount] = useState(1);
 onPress={() => {
     toResult();
     setCount(count + 1);

const toResult = () => {
    navigation.navigate('Result',  {count})
  }
```

Comment: "RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded" typically means that you have infinite recursion somewhere, but I don't see any option for that in the code that you shared. Can you edit your question to show the entire stack trace, and the minimum code that we can reproduce the problem with? Also see [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: if i change in my function update to set it will worked, but i need to update only one field